# select change event fires during binding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm building a multi-step form using knockoutjs in my asp.net mvc 5 application.

the problem is, during binding, the change event for my dropdown is firing. similar to this issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142446/knockoutjs-select-change-event-gets-fired-when-binding).

I have tried everything suggested in the post above, but the event is still firing twice.

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Step1.Country, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Step1.Country, Model.Step1.Countries, new { @class = "select-country", @style = "width: 100%;", data_bind = "value: Model.Step1.Country" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Step1.State, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Step1.State, Model.Step1.States, new { @style = "width: 100%;", data_bind = "value: Model.Step1.State" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Step1.City, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Step1.City, new { maxlength = "50", @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: Model.Step1.City" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Wizard Plugin:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.Wizard = function (options) {

    //Set the form of the current wizard
    var $form = $("#" + options.formId);

    var ViewModel = function (d, m) {
        var self = this;

        self.Model = ko.mapping.fromJS(d, m);

        self.Model.GeneralErrors = ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.Model.Errors(), function (item) {
                return !!item.MemberName;
            });
        });

        self.Model.Step1.Country.subscribe(function (value) {
            alert(value);
            console.log(value);
        });

        self.SelectionChanged = function (element) {

        }

    }

    var vm = new ViewModel(options.model, options.mapping);

    ko.applyBindings(vm, this[0]);

    vm.UpdateOnChange = true;

    return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#WizardWrapper").Wizard({
            formId: "WizardForm",
            model: @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))),
            url: "/DataCollection/@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()/",
            mapping: {
                create: function (options){
                    var m = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
                    return m;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks user3297291,

thanks, adding valueAllowUnset stopped the event firing when binding and fires when a selection is made.

However, just one problem,the event fires again during postback when save is click. the event is triggered again by

```
 ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.Model);
```

in the ajax post below.

Save Event:

```
            self.Next = function (element) {
            var validator = $(element).closest("form").validate();

            if ($(element).closest("form").valid()) {
               $.ajax({
                    url: options.url + action,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: ko.toJSON(self.Model),
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.UpdateOnChange = false;
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.Model);
                        self.UpdateOnChange = true;
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
            } else {
                validator.focusInvalid();
            }
        }
```

Button:

```
<input data-bind="event: { click: Next.bind($data, $element) }" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-prev btn-sky" value="Next" />
```

**Update:**

In order to fix the issue with the subscription triggering again after Country is updated, I used this [solution](http://ryanrahlf.com/creating-a-dirty-flag-in-your-knockout-js-view-model/) with a few changes.

```
self.dirty = ko.observable(false);
        self.selectedCountry = ko.observable();

        self.dirtyCalculations = ko.computed(function () {
            var value = self.Model.Step1.Country();

            if (value == self.selectedCountry()) {
                self.selectedCountry(null);
                self.dirty(false);
            } else {
                self.selectedCountry(value);
                self.dirty(true);
            }
        });

self.Model.Step1.Country.subscribe(function (value) {
            if (value != undefined && self.dirty()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: options.url + "GetState",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: ko.toJSON(self.Model),
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.UpdateOnChange = false;
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.Model);
                        self.UpdateOnChange = true;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                self.resetDirtyFlag();
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you please post your HTML code

Comment: I have added the HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple answer:** You could (mis?)use the `valueAllowUnset` binding.

```js
var VM = function(initial) {
  this.selection = ko.observable(initial);
  this.updateCount = ko.observable(0);

  this.selection.subscribe(function() {
    this.updateCount(this.updateCount() + 1);
  }, this);


}

ko.applyBindings(new VM(1), document.querySelector(".example1"));
ko.applyBindings(new VM(2), document.querySelector(".example2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="example1">
  <h1>with valueAllowUnset</h1>
  <select name="" id="" data-bind="value: selection, valueAllowUnset: true">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    Updates: <span data-bind="text: updateCount"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example2">
  <h1>without valueAllowUnset</h1>
  <select name="" id="" data-bind="value: selection">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    Updates: <span data-bind="text: updateCount"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternative solution:** I'd suggest to use the `options` binding to render your options via knockout instead of MVC. It makes it a bit easier to debug client side. But this might be personal preference.

Comment: thanks, adding valueAllowUnset stopped the event firing when binding and fires when a selection is made.  

However, just one problem,the event fires again during postback when save is click.

Comment: You'll need to show what happens on save for me to be able to understand what's wrong. Also note that we're not using `valueAllowUnset` for its intended purpose, so it might backfire. (It allows your select box to have any value, whether it's in your options list or not)

Comment: You subscribe to changes to `Country`. When you reapply `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, model)`, it sets the observable `Country` with a new value. This triggers the subscription.

Comment: Yes, anyway to stop that, if possible?

Comment: The subscription should only trigger if the new `Country` is different from the old one (i.e.: if the `data` that comes back after the save differs from the current client state). You might want to formulate a new question if you can't get it to work. Check out a minimum example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw4nwm0b/